# How can I change the autonumber field to increment differently?

Tags: ms-access-2010, autonumber

I have a situation in which I need to make an "a" and "b" for each record. Long story short, it's for a report. Is it possible to change the auto number increment to increase by .5, or make a record "1a" and "1b"?

Comment: Long story short. NO. You need a Number field for this sorts of operation.

Comment: In general, autonumbers should be used to uniquely identify a row in the table, nothing more.  Don't count on them being sequential.  In most cases, autonumber values shouldn't be exposed to end users.  You need an additional column in your table.